# On domains of identities

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I've got a somewhat naive question: Let $x$ be a real number. Suppose that the identity $f(x)-g(x)=h(x)$ holds if and only if $x>a$. Suppose also that for $x>a, g(x)$ is identical to some function $j(x)$ such that $f(x)-j(x)=h(x)$ holds for all $x>b.$ Does it necessarily follow that $a\leq b$ ?

Comment: Yep! @symplectomorphic is correct! I removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Not necessarily. Look at this simple example:

Suppose $f(x)=h(x)=0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.
Let $g(x)=1$ for $x\leq 10$, and $g(x)=0$ for $x>10$.
And, let $j(x)=1$ for $x\leq 0$, and $j(x)=0$ for $x>0$.

With $a=10$ and $b=0$, every hypothesis is satisfied and $a>b$.